# Is there any advantage to represent 3D rotations in $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ rather than $\mathrm{SO}(3)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization, representation-theory, lie-groups, rotations

If I want to solve an optimization problem and search for a rotation matrix, is there any advantage to represent the rotation matrix variable in $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ rather than $\mathrm{SO}(3)$?

Any intuitive explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The fact that you can do everything with quaternion multiplication often makes computations easier. There's no easy way to write a parametrization of $SO(3)$, although it's easy to write a single rotation as a rotation through some angle around some particular axis.

Comment: It's true that quaternions are more compact and computationally more efficient. But let's say we can use optimization over Riemannian manifolds algorithms and the relative computational gain is not of particular interest. Now, is there anything interesting about the structure of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ to make the optimization problem "nicer" or it's simply an alternative?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any of this algorithmic optimizsation stuff, so I cannot comment further.